# Apache mod_proxy with automatic authentication

Tags: proxy, apache-http-server

I am setting up a proxy in apache through the directive `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` for some urls:

```
ProxyPass /mypath http://myotherserver.com
ProxyPassReverse /mypath http://myotherserver.com
```

However, `myotherserver.com` require a (basic) authentication. If I don't do anything, this authentication is passed to the final client. For some reason, I don't want that and I would like to add the credentials directly in my apache configuration. How can I do that ?
I tried:

```
ProxyPass /mypath http://user:pass@myotherserver.com
ProxyPassReverse /mypath http://user:pass@myotherserver.com
```

But it does not seems to work. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have actually found the solution. I hope it can be useful for other people:

Run the following python script to get your authentification `hash`:

```
import base64
hash = base64.b64encode(b'user:password')
```

Add the following directive in your apache configuration:

```
<Location /mypath>
RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic $hash"
</Location>
```

where `$hash` is replaced with the previously computed string.

Make sure that `mod_proxy` and `mod_headers` are available (`a2enmod proxy` and `a2enmod headers`). Restart apache2 and you are done :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @ThR37 - this is more of a comment for your answer, but can't format it there. :/

I needed to do it with mod_rewrite, but your method was used:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  SSLProxyEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/34506a81-1a6d-4596-beaf-580da9c98cca$
  SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "/34506a81-1a6d-4596-beaf-580da9c98cca" DOAUTH
  RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" env=DOAUTH
  RewriteRule /34506a81-1a6d-4596-beaf-580da9c98cca https://www.example.com/my/path [P,L]
  ProxyPassReverse /34506a81-1a6d-4596-beaf-580da9c98cca https://www.example.com/my/path
```